# my fstream always fails

Tags: c++

Please help, I have the following little snip code to test fsteam, but it always fails, and my strace file following after the code. 
It works in unix but not in linux. 
Thanks for your help.

---

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {

        fstream filestr;

        filestr.open ("test.txt",ios::out | ios::in | ios::app );
        if(filestr.bad()) 
        {        
                cout << "Bad input." << endl; 
        }        
        if(filestr.fail()) 
        {        
                cout << "Open failed." << endl; 
        }       
        filestr << " dsgesvsvds";

        filestr.close();

        return 0;
}
```

---

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 83 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x10754000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8cf1e9d000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8cf1e9e000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffd262c040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/tls", 0x7fffd262c040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffd262c040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/roscodev/rosco/bin/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffd262c040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/roscodev/rosco/bin/tls", 0x7fffd262c040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/roscodev/rosco/bin/x86_64", 0x7fffd262c040) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/roscodev/rosco/bin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=80518, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 80518, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b8cf1e9f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\364\304\3528\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=976312, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x38eac00000, 3145600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x38eac00000
mprotect(0x38eace6000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x38eaee5000, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe5000) = 0x38eaee5000
mmap(0x38eaeee000, 73600, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x38eaeee000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`>\200\3438\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=615136, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x38e3800000, 2629848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x38e3800000
mprotect(0x38e3882000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x38e3a81000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x81000) = 0x38e3a81000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\36\200\3468\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=58400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8cf1eb3000
mmap(0x38e6800000, 2151784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x38e6800000
mprotect(0x38e680d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x38e6a0d000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd000) = 0x38e6a0d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/products/oracle/11.2.0/client/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/roscodev/rosco/bin/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\332\1\3438\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1722304, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x38e3000000, 3502424, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x38e3000000
mprotect(0x38e314e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x38e334e000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14e000) = 0x38e334e000
mmap(0x38e3353000, 16728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x38e3353000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8cf1eb4000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8cf1eb5000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2b8cf1eb4bf0) = 0
mprotect(0x38e334e000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x38e3a81000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x38eaee5000, 24576, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x38e2e1b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b8cf1e9f000, 80518)           = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8cf1e9f000
write(1, "Open failed.\n", 13Open failed.
)          = 13
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
```

Should be

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: I got it figured out: the ios::in and ios::out together causing the problem, so I took ios::in out, it becomes
        filestr.open ("test.txt",ios::out |ios::app );
then it works fine.But  WHY??????

Comment: Oh. Maybe because `fstream` is already for input and output. `ifstream` is for input only, and `ofstream` is for output only. You should try setting neither `ios::out` nor `ios::in`

Answer (score 1):

You are using C++, and standard headers do not have a `.h` extension like in C. Therefore, you need to `#include` `<fstream>` and `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine for me under Ubuntu 9.10 if I correct your #include errors (should be `#include <fstream>` and `#include <iostream>` -- no .h). But I suspect that isn't your problem, since that results in a compile error. Might you have a permissions error? If I create `test.txt` and remove write permissions, I get the "Open failed." message.

Comment: thank you. I tried the version without .h under redhat linux, fails on me too. I also tried touch a file first before running it, no luck. hopefully someone could give me some insights.

Answer (score 0):

I run it in DevC++ on windows8.1 after correcting header files and it is working fine.